# PHP Text Clickable

Tags: php, regex

I use this preg_replace to change text urls to clickable :

```
echo preg_replace("~(https?://(?:www\.)?[^\s]+)~i","<a href='$1'>$1</a>",$x);
```

Working fine if i want convert : `lorem ipsum https://domain.com/xxx` to `lorem ipsum <a href='https://domain.com/xxx'>https://domain.com/xxx</a>`

But i have different goal right here, i want to convert : `lorem ipsum https://domain.com/xxx` to `<a href='https://domain.com/xxx'>lorem ipsum </a>`

Comment: how will know if its one word of text or 10, is that the whole string you will have every time? you need to give some more user case demos.

Comment: @Dagon its always 1 link in 1 string

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [preg_split — Split string by a regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
<?php

    $str=" lorem ipsum https://domain.com/xxx";

    $split= preg_split("#(https\:\/\/)|(http\:\/\/)#",$str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); //split on https:// or http://

    echo '<a href="'.$split[1].$split[2].'">'.trim($split[0]).'</a>'; //glue the 3 pieces back together

    //<a href="https://domain.com/xxx">lorem ipsum</a>

?>
```